# Why 2 home pages?

Tags: homepage, plugin-jetpack

All my site in WP have to 2 home pages in jet pack stats, any idea why ?
https://prnt.sc/m03pws
https://prnt.sc/m03qed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"Home"** and **"Home page / archives"** are not the same thing. Instead, they are different.

If you have a static front page on your site, the **“Home page / Archives”** item in your stats can refer to a couple things:

- Your blog (posts) page, if you have one for your site
- Any blog archives page, such as posts from a particular month, in a
  particular category, or by a particular author